# Why doesn`t work call to https Rest API using curl in php?

Tags: php, rest, curl

I am trying to make an API call with this code:

```php
<?php
    $service_url = 'https://favqs.com/api/qotd.json';
    $curl = curl_init($service_url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    $json_objekat = json_decode($curl_response);
    echo $json_objekat->quote->author.'<br>';
    echo $json_objekat->quote->body.'<br>';
?>
```

This code is saved as a php file in www (root) folder on my local machine. I use a WAMP server.

When I open this file from WAMP it says:

> Notice:
>   Trying to get property of non-object in C:\wamp\www\IzdavackaKuca\javniServis.php on line 10
>   Trying to get property of non-object in C:\wamp\www\IzdavackaKuca\javniServis.php on line 10
>   Trying to get property of non-object in C:\wamp\www\IzdavackaKuca\javniServis.php on line 11
>   Trying to get property of non-object in C:\wamp\www\IzdavackaKuca\javniServis.php on line 11

I checked php extensions option `php_curl` on WAMP and I don't know if I should check some other options. I don't know if there is some problem with my WAMP server or what the problem is, because I have sent this same code to a couple of other people and they say that it works on their computer. I don't know where the error is so I hope someone can help me.
Thank you!

Comment: What is the response that you get?

Comment: Print out `$curl_response` to see what it is, the problem is the `json_decode` is failing, so the last two lines are not going to work.

Comment: @u_mulder        When I use $curl_responce just how Poiz wrote below, I get responce  string 'Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to favqs.com:443 ' (length=58)     and when I change my code like Minh Thanh wrote, I don`t get alert about error any longer, but I don`t see anything, just empty screen...It doesn`t work. Do you know why is that?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you really otherwise do; i imagine that you may not have a Problem with your WAMP Server. The Problem i found is that the URL **https://favqs.com/api/qotd.json** has an ***Unknown SSL Protocol*** according to the Error Message. Check it out yourself:

```
<?php

    $defaults = array(
        CURLOPT_URL             => 'https://favqs.com/api/qotd.json',
        CURLOPT_POST            => false,
        CURLOPT_HEADER          => false,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER  => false,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST  => false,
    );
    $curl               = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, $defaults);
    $curl_response      = curl_exec($curl);
    $json_objekat       = json_decode($curl_response);

    // DUMP THE CURL-ERROR INFORMATION:
    var_dump(curl_error($curl));
    curl_close($curl);
```

**##EDITS##**
Depending on what you are attempting to do; i think you may need an Access Code for this to work correctly and you can get it here:[image]

And when you do; all you have to do is modify your code and add the Authorisation code...

Comment: Yes, I see, with your code, I get the answer string 'Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to favqs.com:443 ' (length=58)

Comment: But what can I do now? Why on computers of some my friends it works?

Comment: You can read about the cause of this Error here: http://blog.techstacks.com/2010/03/3-common-causes-of-unknown-ssl-protocol-errors-with-curl.html however,  since curl failed in this case you may try another approach that doesn't require curl.

Comment: Hey! I actually checked out the site https://favqs.com/api/  and i think I found out your Problem. You don't seem to have added your Authorization token. Do you have any Authorization token?

Comment: No, but not all services need authorization token and this seemed not to need token...It wrights if you see: An app token is required to access our API except for the Quote of the Day and that is my service - Quote of the Day. So I thing token is not needed...But I will read about this error so I hope I will find something...Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When you use json_decode. It will transfer your json string to array, not object. Then, if you wanna take arguments from that response. You should code like this

```
echo $json_objekat['quote']['author'].'<br>';
echo $json_objekat['quote']['body'].'<br>';
```

Comment: When I code like this, nothing happens, actually, there is no allert about any error, but also it doesn`t work anything, I just see empty page with nothing written on it. Do you no why is that?

Comment: Then you should use
`var_dump($json_objekat)`
To see what exactly in this response